# How to Change Window Size in DirectX 11 Desktop Application

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d, directx-11, hlsl

I am writing DirectX 11 shader program based on the tutorial in this msdn link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj552952.aspx

When I run it, it is in full screen. Changing the swap chain size does not change window size as expected. Is there a way to change the window size? I simply want to create the window in a fixed size and if it happens to cover the whole screen, I do want it to be exclusive full screen.

I can get HWND from swap chain with IDXGISwapChain1::GetHwnd method. Would this handle be useful to resize the window?

The corresponding code can be found here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the [Direct3D Win32 Game](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) VS 2013 Win32 desktop app template which handles window resizing, although it does not support full-screen exclusive-mode transitions.

The basic handling for window resizing for Direct3D 11 in Win32 desktop apps is to update your Window Procedure to handle `WM_SIZE`, but you need to cope with a number of cases.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static bool s_in_sizemove = false;
    static bool s_minimized = false;

    switch (message)
    {

...

    case WM_SIZE:
        if (wParam == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
        {
// The window was minimized (you should probably suspend the application)
            if (!s_minimized)
            {
                s_minimized = true;
            }
        }
        else if (s_minimized)
        {
// The window was minimized and is now restored (resume from suspend)
            s_minimized = false;
        }
        else if ( !s_in_sizemove )
        {
// Here is where you handle the swapchain resize for maximize or unmaximize
        }
        break;

    case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
// We want to avoid trying to resizing the swapchain as the user does the 'rubber band' resize
        s_in_sizemove = true;
        break;

    case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
        s_in_sizemove = false;
// Here is the other place where you handle the swapchain resize after the user stops using the 'rubber-band' 
        break;

    case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
        {
// We want to prevent the window from being set too tiny
            auto info = reinterpret_cast<MINMAXINFO*>(lParam);
            info->ptMinTrackSize.x = 320;
            info->ptMinTrackSize.y = 200;
        }
        break;

...
```

To do the Direct3D swapchain resize:

- Call `ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets` with nulls to unbind the render target and any depth/stencil buffer.
- Release your render target view and depth/stencil view, and any other references to the original back buffer or the depth/stencil buffer.
- Call `D3D11DeviceContext::Flush` to let those changes finish up
- Call `IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers` to resize the backbuffer to the new size. Be sure you respond to `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED` and `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET` failures.
- Do the same setup again as you did initially for the new size: create the render target view for the new back buffer, create a new the depth stencil view for your depth/stencil buffer that matches the new backbuffer size (optional), and reset the viewport size.

Since this procedure makes some assumptions about the application, it was omitted from the Win32 desktop tutorial for simplicity. This case is handled for the Direct3D Win32 Game template, and the Windows Store DirectX app template, and the Windows phone DirectX app template.

There is no such thing as 'full-screen exclusive mode' for Windows Store apps or Windows phone apps, so those templates don't implement it. For the Win32 desktop tutorial and the Direct3D Win32 Game template, I use the following to ensure I don't have to cope with it:

```
dxgiFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(hwnd, DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER);
```

I hope to revisit how to extend the Direct3D Win32 Game template to support full-screen exclusive mode, but I've not gotten to it yet.

Comment: I don't think ResizeBuffers will change the window size? The template in your link does not have shader code and I do need the exclusive full screen mode. Actually I simply want to create the window in a fixed size and if it happens to cover the whole screen, I needs be exclusive full screen.

Comment: There are three choices: (1) Make the window full screen with a fixed size and don't include the controls to move/resize it, (2) make the window fullscreen with a fixed size and don't include any controls or border (sometimes known as "fake fullscreen"), (3) actually use DXGI to force it into an exclusive full-screen mode.

Comment: This question is quite old, but as someone who just researched this, there is a snipped of code to deal with resizing in the official DXGI programming guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Handling_Window_Resizing